# Why isn't sed/awk capturing groups the way my regex says it should?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, cygwin

I've got a regex here that works according to the site:

https://regex101.com/r/doj4We/1

regex: `<<act ("([^"\\]|\\.)*")`

text:

```
<<act "want" "don't want">><</act>>

<<act "\"want\"" "don't want">><</act>>
```

Group 1 is supposed to capture "want" and "\"want\"", respectively, and according to the site, it does.

But if I take this text and save it in a file, then execute this command:

```
cat tmp | sed -Ern 's/<<act ("([^"\\]|\\.)*")/\1/p'
```

This is the output:

```
"want" "don't want">><</act>>
"\"want\"" "don't want">><</act>>
```

Why is sed behaving differently from the way this website says it should? I noticed the same problem when I tried to use awk's gensub like this:

```
cat tmp | awk '{ r = gensub(/<<act ("([^"\\]|\\.)*")/, "\\1", "g"); print r;}'
```

For what it's worth, I'm using cygwin.

Comment: So, you are trying to extract the text matched at regex101.com, aren't you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew group 1, yes

Comment: Just add `.*` at the end of the pattern, `sed -En 's/<<act ("([^"\]|\\.)*").*/\1/p'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay that fixed it. Why do I have to do that?

Comment: If that is the output you want, why are you not using `awk` alone? E.g., `awk 'NF > 1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf (i>2)?" %s":"%s", $i; print ""}' tmp` ? If you just want the 2nd field, then `awk 'NF > 1 {print $2}' tmp`

Comment: Web sites like regex101 tell you what a given regexp means **to that web site**, not what they mean to any other tool. They're practically useless for doing anything with regexps for UNIX tools as they don't take into account the regexp variant any tool uses, the options the tool takes, delimiters, extensions, if/where backreferences are supported, different functions, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton okay, well is there another website that's worth using? It's pretty difficult to troubleshoot regex otherwise, unless you ask someone

Comment: No, there is no website worth using, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `sed`  with the `s`ubstitution command, so you are *searching and replacing* the found matches. You want to get Group 1 value, so you need to match the part before and *after* the capturing group to remove them to keep just what you want.

You can use

```
sed -En 's/<<act ("([^"\]|\\.)*").*/\1/p'
#                                ^^
```

The `.*` will match any text and it will get removed. This also implies you can only have `<<act`  at the start of the string. Also note that since bracket expressions do not support regex escapes, `[^"\]` is enough, no need to double escape `\`.

A note on the options: `-E` enables the POSIX ERE regex syntax, `n` suppresses the default line output, `p` prints the result of the substitution.

Comment: I don't understand why `[^"\]` isn't throwing a syntax error. Most tools interpret `\]` within a bracket expression as meaning a literal `]` so I'd have expected that to throw a syntax error about an unterminated bracket expression. Bracket expressions do support regexp escapes - try `echo 'a\bc' | sed 's/[\c]//g'` vs `echo 'a\bc' | sed 's/[\\c]//g'`

Comment: @EdMorton By regex escape I meant a literal char escaped with a literal backslash. I did not mean the special notations like `\cx`, `\dxxx` or `\oxxx` and `\xxx`. ``[^"\]`` works because the `]`, when preceded with a ``\``, does not form a regex escape inside a bracket expression and ``\`` is thus treated as a literal. ``sed 's/[\c]//g'``  fails because the `]` is no longer closing the bracket expression and the pattern becomes invalid.

Comment: I didn't know there was anything special about `\c`, I was trying to use a literal backslash and one other literal character, I do see different behavior when I try it with `\j`, sorry for the bad example. Apparently this is a difference between some awks and some seds - with GNU awk `echo 'a[]\j' | awk '{gsub(/[\]/,"")}1'` outputs an `unterminated regexp` syntax error as I expected while the equivalent with GNU sed `echo 'a[]\j' | sed -E 's/[\]//g'` outputs `a[]j` which would require `awk '{gsub(/[\\]/,"")}1'`, i.e. escapes in the bracket expression, to get the same output.

Comment: I just tried GNU grep and it behaves the same way as GNU sed.

Comment: @EdMorton It is the same in a lot of other environments, Tcl, R TRE library, Oracle, etc. (all the POSIX based regex libraries). Also, see [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html): "*One key syntactic difference is that the backslash is NOT a metacharacter in a POSIX bracket expression. So in POSIX, the regular expression `[\d]` matches a ``\`` or a `d`.*"

Comment: Yes, I know what POSIX says about it, but GNU tools have a lof of extensions and I expected the ability to escape `]`in the middle of a bracket expression to be common to all of them, not unique to gawk.

Comment: @EdMorton That is also a known thing you cannot place `]` anywhere in the bracket expression, only at the start of it. Just because you cannot use these regex escapes.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what POSIX says and that's what I'm saying above - that some tools, e.g. GNU awk, have an extension that accept escapes in the middle of a bracket expression and so do allow an escaped `]` in the middle of a bracket expression, e.g. try `echo 'a]bcde' | gawk '{gsub(/[d\]c]/,"")}1'`. I just expected all GNU tools to behave the same way and apparently I was wrong about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `<<act ("([^"\\]|\\.)*")` would work **as is** with `awk`. Moreovver, if you're using `gnu-awk` then you don't really need to do any substitution also. It can be done in a single `match` function as this:

```
awk 'match($0, /<<act ("([^"\\]|\\.)*")/, m) { print m[1] }' file
```

```
"want"
"\"want\""
```

For POSIX awk you can use this `awk`:

```
/awk '$1 == "<<act" && $2 ~ /"([^"\\]|\\.)*"/{ print $2 }' file
```

Comment: "Your regex would work as is with awk" Not when I tried with gensub.

Comment: Please check this demo: https://ideone.com/yywJSR and you don't need `gensub` or `gsub`, just use simple `match` as I showed.

Comment: I understand, I guess I found your wording to be a little ambiguous. I thought you were saying it could also work as I already had it. the word "Moreovver" suggested that

Comment: Yes I meant the regex you have shown in question or on regex101 will work without any changes. I am adding a non-gnu command as well